# Creating flashable zip from Android source code

Tags: android, android-source, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-build

I compile the latest Android source code successfully using official guides, but I don't want to use fastboot flashall to flash the OS onto the device. I do not have USB access to the server I use for compilation. I want a binary output of the code I build.

Any idea how to create a flashable zip code out of Android source code?

Comment: I know some people may ask why, so the answer is I am compiling on a remote server.

Comment: What guide are you following? I found sources that say otapackage is not a build target for AOSP

Comment: @cricket_007 alternative?

Comment: I'm not sure what your Makefile looks like

Comment: It's the one you get when you build the Android source code.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, so I'll post it as a comment. Like you, I also use a remote build server but need to flash a local device. The easiest way I've found to do this is to use SSHFS to mount the remote filesystem to the local machine that the target device is connected to. From there, fastboot, adb, etc. run on the local machine with the remote mount work as usual. Yes, flashing takes longer, but you are basically doing the file transfer and flash in one step.

Comment: I should mention that the 'flash over SSHFS' technique should really only be done over fast-ish, reliable connections. If there is a risk of the network dropping out mid-way during the flash, you should transfer the .IMG or .ZIP files first and then flash locally. Depending on the device and specific conditions, an interruption during the flash process could lead to unpleasant results.

Answer (score 2):

If you would create a full update zip package (system, boot, and recovery partitions), you can use for a hypothetical tardis device:

```
# first, build the target-files .zip
% . build/envsetup.sh && lunch tardis-eng
% mkdir dist_output
% make dist DIST_DIR=dist_output
  [...]
% ls -l dist_output/*target_files*
-rw-r----- 1 user eng  69965275 Sep 29 15:51 tardis-target_files.zip
```

The target-files .zip contains everything needed to construct OTA packages. Now you can construct it with:

```
% ./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files \
    dist_output/tardis-target_files.zip ota_update.zip
unzipping target target-files...
done.
% ls -l ota_update.zip
-rw-r----- 1 user eng 62236561 Sep 29 15:58 ota_update.zip
```

The ota_update.zip is now ready to be sent to test devices (everything is signed with the test key). For user devices, generate and use your own private keys

More info https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/tools

Comment: How we can create .img file to burn with USB? for example aml_upgrade_package.img

Comment: maybe the android-x86 project can be useful https://www.android-x86.org